# Java ResultSet Missing Final Record if Where Clause included in SQL command

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a very simple java application intended to reach into a db and pull out a resultset based on an input on a java form. However, any parameters added to the SQL Statement end with a loss of the final record in the recordset (though it does seem to pull the proper result.)

The below code results in my entire dataset, with example at the top (as expected.)

```
Name|Location|Details
A|Here|7854
A|There|7854
B|Here|8761
C|Gone|5312

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

try {
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=$DBname;user=$user;password=$password";
     String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
     Connection dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
     Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs;
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from schema.table");
     tblServers.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
     dbconn.close();
 } catch (Exception f) {
     System.err.println("Downloading Servers from the Database Failed! ");
     System.err.println(f.getMessage());
 }  

}

private DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

ResultSetMetaData rsmetaData = rs.getMetaData();

//Get Column Names
int numCols = rsmetaData.getColumnCount();
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
for (int column = 1; column <= numCols; column++) {
    columnNames.add(rsmetaData.getColumnName(column));
}                   
//Iterate through rows
Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> rows = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= numCols ; colIndex++) {
        rows.add(rs.getObject(colIndex));
    }
    data.add(rows);
}
return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
            }

);
```

Now if I change nothing but the SQL line to any variant with a "where" clause, like:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from schema.table where name = 'A'");
```

I get:

```
Name|Location|Details
A|Here|7854
```

Or if searched for B, I get no results:

```
Name|Location|Details
|||
```

Any ideas are appreciated; I'm sure this is something extremely simple.

@Sasha: Yes, I am sure I am getting 1 result. I have tried with many permutations and it always results in either a blank resultset (but with accurate headers) or headers, and resultset, minus the final row.

@PM77-1: As soon as the code spits back the return (data, ColumnNames) my JTable has the resultset visible to the user.

@Glenn: On your suggestion, I added System.out.println(data) and 'System.out.println(rs)' to just before the 'return new DefaultTableModel'. The output is [] and SQLServerResultSet:1, respectively

@JohnnyAW The results for that with a where clause are the same as my comment above - no "tests" appear in the syslog. When I remove the where clause, I get a bunch of syslog entries with "test" prefacing my records.

Correction: I get "testtesttest" to the sum of 8 tests, my entire testing recordset. One test gets missed when I have a Where clause.

Comment: The `Select * ...... where name = 'A'` must get two result, as in your database there are two rows. Are you sure it gets only one result?

Comment: At what point and how do you check the content of your `resultset`?

Comment: Where are you printing out the results?  Trying printing the `data` vector before returning the DefaultTableModel.  It could be that the consumer of the DefaultTableModel is assuming the first row is a header row.

Comment: i cant see an error in this code, could you put a sys.out.print("test") into while (rs.next()) {...} to count the while-executions?

Comment: Doesn't really make sense that `data` is empty before your return. But here is one more idea: verify that none of your names has whitespace. ie nothing like name = 'A ' (which would fail your match). You could check with `WHERE name LIKE '%A%'` rather than using equals.

Comment: print everything you have got inside `while(rs.next()){...}`, this ensures you you have got the data from the database, so check for the next possibilities